# Cant seem to make a refresh button to refresh an API call in python

Tags: python, json, rest, user-interface, tkinter

I have built a simple python script to call to nano pool API to retrieve some information and I would like to add a button that refreshes the info. I have tried to build a button that recalls the JSON data and place it in a command for the refresh tk button but no info is refreshed and I get no errors 
//I apologize for the crappy coding, self taught and only have been coding for a few weeks//

```
class Application(Frame):
    def refresh(self):
        main_api = "https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/user/
        ethUSD = "https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/prices"
        hashRate = "https://api.nanopool.org/v1/eth/reportedhashrate/
        json_data = requests.get(main_api).json()
        json_dataETHUSD = requests.get(ethUSD).json()
        hashRateJson = requests.get(hashRate).json()

    def createWidgets(self):


        self.refresh = Button(self)
        self.refresh["text"] = "Refresh",
        self.refresh["command"] = self.refresh

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "left"})




    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.infoBoxes()
```

Comment: Please try to condense the next example to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: im sorry, im not sure what you may or may not need because I have no idea why it wont refresh : def refresh is where I tried to make the command for the button to call the API info again but nothing gets updated and i get no errors when the button is clicked

Comment: If your problem is with a button calling a refresh function, all you need is the button and the refresh button, and maybe one text widget. You don't most of the code in `infoBoxes`.

Comment: have removed most of what i thought was not needed. I would like to make a button called "refresh" to recall the API for the current data but nothing seems to happen when i click my refresh button

Answer (score 1):

your are overwriting self.refresh, the method name, when you create button :|. Also commands i prefer to it's properties on instantiation. Instead try
**self.button** = Tk.Button(master=self, text='Refresh', command=self.refresh)